# Matrix Substitution & Operator Adjustment

Tags: pattern-matching

How can I effectively substitute some variables in an expression with matrixes, while adapting the operators accordingly, to maintain the intended meaning and operations?
For example, given a list like {a + b x y^3 + c, x} and matrixes named xMatrix yMatrix both are symmetric and of size n, how can I replace x with xMatrix, y with yMatrix and adapt the operators and constants to obtain the following list: {a * IdentityMatrix[n] + b * IdentityMatrix[n] . xMatrix . yMatrix . yMatrix . yMatrix + c * IdentityMatrix[n], xMatrix}

Comment: It is unclear (to me at least) what you are asking. The sentence would be incoherent even if had an ending.

Comment: What is the size of matrices? So you want to replace each of the symbols in `(a,b,c,d,e,f)` `IdentityMatrix[#]`?  lets says size is 2 for now. Do you mean now you want `a` on the diagonal? same for `b,c,d,e,f` ? And what should the matrix `x` be? Unknowns?  A small example will go long way to make your question more clear. Any way, for replacement look up the `/.` command also `ConstantArray` might be useful.

Comment: My apologies for the previous confusion. I have edited the question for clarity. I hope this is now more understandable.

Comment: Your problem is somewhat ill-defined, because `x y^3` in Mathematica is assumed to be commutative, but `Dot[xMatrix, MatrixPower[yMatrix,3]]` is not. Perhaps your original expression should be `{a + b x.y^3+x, x}`. *Or*, perhaps you might rethink your approach to the problem. In any case, `{a + b x y^3 + c, x} /. {x^n_. :> MatrixPower[xMatrix, n], 
   y^n_. :> MatrixPower[yMatrix, n]} /. 
 a_MatrixPower b_MatrixPower :> a.b` works for your example, but won't work in general.

Comment: Inspired by @march's insightful contribution, we can now tackle even more complex examples like this one: {{a + b f x y^3 z + c, e x}, d x y z^2, x}}. As you'll see, we require a concrete real matrix in place of a placeholder like xMatrix. To ensure proper evaluation, we've incorporated Hold and ReleaseHold operations into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @march's insightful contribution, we can now tackle even more complex examples like this one: `{{a + b f x y^3 z + c, e x}, d x y z^2, x}}`. As you'll see, we require a concrete real matrix in place of a placeholder like xMatrix. To ensure proper evaluation, we've incorporated Hold and ReleaseHold operations into the code.

```
xMatrix = IdentityMatrix[2];
yMatrix = IdentityMatrix[2] + 1;
zMatrix = IdentityMatrix[2] + 2;
nOrder = 2;
ReleaseHold[
 Expand[{{a + b f x y^3 z + c, e x}, d x y z^2, 
      x} /. {Plus[num___] -> 
       Plus[Map[# Hold[IdentityMatrix[nOrder]] &, {num} ] /. 
         List -> Sequence]}] /. {x^n_. :> 
     MatrixPower[Hold[xMatrix], n], 
    y^n_. :> MatrixPower[Hold[yMatrix], n], 
    z^n_. :> MatrixPower[Hold[zMatrix], n]} /. (Times[num___, 
     te___Hold, t2___MatrixPower] -> Times[num] Dot[te, t2])]
```